# How to preprocess a text to remove stopwords?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, stop-words

I would like to remove a list of stopwords, namely the ones in

```
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
print(STOPWORDS)
```

In gensim, this should be pretty straightforward with [`remove_stopwords` function](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.py).

My code to read the text and remove the stopwords is the following:

```
def read_text(text_path):
  text = []
  with open(text_path) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
      text.append(simple_preprocess(remove_stopwords(line)))
  return text

text = read_text('/content/text.txt')
text =  [x for x in text if x]
text[:3]
```

This is the output I get that contains words such as "we" or "however" which should have been removed from the [original text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JKIPRb9y6XK7dnVybfwm5Yoz_lBV7mLP/view?usp=sharing) though for instance "the" has been correctly removed from the first setence. I am very confused... what am I missing here?

```
[['clinical', 'guidelines', 'management', 'ibd'],
 ['polygenetic',
  'risk',
  'scores',
  'add',
  'predictive',
  'power',
  'clinical',
  'models',
  'response',
  'anti',
  'tnfα',
  'therapy',
  'inflammatory',
  'bowel',
  'disease'],
 ['anti',
  'tumour',
  'necrosis',
  'factor',
  'alpha',
  'tnfα',
  'therapy',
  'widely',
  'management',
  'crohn',
  'disease',
  'cd',
  'ulcerative',
  'colitis',
  'uc',
  'however',
  'patients',
  'respond',
  'induction',
  'therapy',
  'patients',
  'lose',
  'response',
  'time',
  'to',
  'aid',
  'patient',
  'stratification',
  'polygenetic',
  'risk',
  'scores',
  'identified',
  'predictors',
  'response',
  'anti',
  'tnfα',
  'therapy',
  'we',
  'aimed',
  'replicate',
  'association',
  'polygenetic',
  'risk',
  'scores',
  'response',
  'anti',
  'tnfα',
  'therapy',
  'independent',
  'cohort',
  'patients',
  'establish',
  'clinical',
  'validity']]
```

**Text** (complete file available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JKIPRb9y6XK7dnVybfwm5Yoz_lBV7mLP/view?usp=sharing))

Clinical Guidelines for the Management of IBD.

Polygenetic risk scores do not add predictive power to clinical models for response to anti-TNFα therapy in inflammatory bowel disease.
Anti-tumour necrosis factor alpha (TNFα) therapy is widely used in the management of Crohn's disease (CD) and ulcerative colitis (UC). However, up to a third of patients do not respond to induction therapy and another third of patients lose response over time. To aid patient stratification, polygenetic risk scores have been identified as predictors of response to anti-TNFα therapy. We aimed to replicate the association between polygenetic risk scores and response to anti-TNFα therapy in an independent cohort of patients, to establish its clinical validity.

Comment: The answer from @12kadir12 is correct, but as you've tagged your question with `word2vec`, I'd also add: it's not strictly necessary to remove stopwords before doing `Word2Vec` training. Stopwords only have a slight effect on end results, and another parameter in the training, `sample`, already serves to 'thin out' very-common words (even those that might not be on any fixed `STOPWORDS` list) to help other words. So, if the overrepresentation of some words is a major concern, you could also try a more-aggressive `sample` value: smaller than the default of `1e-04`, perhaps `1e-05` or `1e-06`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your remove_stopwords() function is case-sensitive and it doesn't ignore punctuation. For example, 'However' is not in STOPWORDS, but 'however' is in. You should call the simple_preprocess() function first. This should work:

```
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopword_tokens

def read_text(text_path):
  text = []
  with open(text_path) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
      tokens = simple_preprocess(line)
      text.append(remove_stopword_tokens(tokens,stopwords=STOPWORDS))
  return text
```

Comment: can you add the necessary imports to your code? i.e. for both STOPWORDS and remove_stopword_tokens so that it runs end-to-end

Comment: Now, I've added. Note that i've used gensim 4.0.0 library

Comment: Nope, you have used version 4.1.2. See issue here https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/3241

Comment: That's true, I just want to say my version was 4+  :)